# Scala Style Guide formatter for IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am looking for a code formatter for IntelliJ that conforms with the Scala Style Guide: https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/

Would anyone have any recommendations for that?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you [scalafmt](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html).

It has both plugins for IntelliJ and sbt (which is very convenient because you can run formatting or validation of formatting from the command line, which makes it easy to embed it in continuous integration pipeline).

You can also configure it easily with the `.scalafmt` file which will be understood both by the plugin of Intelij and sbt.